# How to draw candle charts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, charts

How can I draw candle charts in C#? Does anybody has any examples with a nice interface?

Comment: what is your platform? windows forms, wpf, asp, console?

Comment: sorry, I'm totally newbie in C# and was thinking in a good starting point. It should be desktop-based. Which one would you suggest me?

Comment: i would go with WPF. telerik has a nice suit of charts, as does visifire.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna search for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the [MSChart](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) and found it to be pretty good.  It supports candlestick charts.  I've used ZedGraph as well but found a few graphical anomalies showed up on my charts but they were otherwise good as well.

Comment: Nice! I still like telerik better, but it ain't an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I use this for stock data but its in VB

```
        With Chart1.ChartAreas("myarea")
            .AxisY.Maximum = (Math.Ceiling((HighValue * 100)) / 100)
            .AxisY.Minimum = (Math.Floor((LowValue * 100)) / 100)
            .AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0.00}"
        End With

        Dim s1 As New Series
        With s1
            .ChartArea = "myarea"
            .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick
            .XValueType = ChartValueType.String
            .YValueType = ChartValueType.Single
            .YValuesPerPoint = 4
            .CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red, PriceUpColor=Green"
        End With


        For i = Globals.GraphColumns - 1 To 0 Step -1
            OutData = Data_Array.Item(i)

            s1.Points.AddXY(OutData.thedate, OutData.high, OutData.low, OutData.close, OutData.open)


        Next


        Chart1.Series.Add(s1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Chart1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asking specifically for solutions in C#, not VB. Please update your answer accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ZedGraph is a very easy-to-use LGPLed charting library that [can handle candlestick charts](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Japanese_Candlestick_Demo).

If you need to save an image to disk, it can do that.  If you need to display an interactive graph that supports zooming/panning, it can do that as well with the excellent ZedGraphControl control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [.netCharting](http://dotnetcharting.com/) library for this and it's pretty good. It supports all sorts of charts - candle included. One thing to watch out for is that with the current version (5.3) you have to reverse the high and low price - a pretty ugly and obvious bug. It's a commercial product, but reasonably priced, so could be worth it, depending on your project.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe ChartDirector can be a good solution

http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdcomdoc/candlestick.htm

Comment: ChartDirector kind of does the job but it's a very crufty, old-fashioned API. I found it pretty painful to work with.

Answer (score -2):

Try [**xamChart**](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamchart.aspx#Overview) Control Trial version from Infragistics.

Here is another [**sample at CodeProject**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_3D_Bar_chart_control.aspx)