# What do you use for drawing line charts using C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, line, charts

I need to draw charts using c# and WPF. I did some work using Visifire. According to you, what is the best way to draw charts in C# and WPF ?

Thanks,
Benoit

---

I tried Dynamic Data Display. It works well but there's a real lake of documentation. I also tried WPF Toolkit. It also works but I think it's very low to draw chart. I'm waiting for the future of dynamic data display.

Thanks all

Comment: This question is subjective. Try asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or making your question more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WPF Toolkit is available. It is free from CodePlex. It contains some nice charting classes.

It can be http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117
. There is some commentary http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx
here.

Original Post On SO [What is the best way to make a graph in WPF? (or in general that would apply to WPF as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545513/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-graph-in-wpf-or-in-general-that-would-apply-to-w)

Also Check
[How to draw candle charts in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650119/how-to-draw-candle-charts-in-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/swordfishcharts.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Your question is tricky: it depends what you're looking for: do you just want to draw simple 2D charts, do you want to have zooming / panning or other interaction and if you want to pay for the component. Here is a list of decent WPF components I'm aware of:

Free WPF charts:

- [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). Supports most important 2D charts and open source. Found [documentation](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Links%20to%20Documentation) hard to get to & navigate.
- [Visiblox](http://www.visiblox.com/) Charts. Support for the most important 2D charts, built in zooming, panning & other interactivity. [Documentation](http://www.visiblox.com/docs) is good, see [examples](http://www.visiblox.com/examples) using it. Free version comes with a watermark.
- [DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) - a nice, open source data visualization library. Unfortunately it's not been updated for a year and a half which is something to keep in mind.
- [AmCharts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/). Supports basic 2D charts. [Documentation](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quickwpfdocs/) is basic. See [examples](http://wpf.amcharts.com/demo/) using it.

Paid tools:

- [Infragistics xamDataChart](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamchart.aspx#Overview). Supports most important 2D charts, zooming and panning. Have no experience on how good documentation is, see [examples](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamchartgallery.aspx#Gallery) using it.
- [Telerik RadChart](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx). Supports lots of 2D charts. [Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/introduction.html) is good, see [examples](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/getting-started/demo-requirements.aspx) using it.

***Full Disclosure:*** I have been heavily involved in development of Visiblox, hence I know that library in much more detail than the others.

Comment: Visiblox link broken.

Answer (score 2):

use PathGemometry in WPF to darw any type of figure , it has its own language.

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

While I thoroughly enjoy working with the Telerik chart controls, they are quite expensive and are overkill for many. There are a number of free charting controls available, however I cannot recommend one, as I have not recently tried any.

In the end, it depends strongly on your requirements. If you need pretty 3d charts, you will want to use a different library than if you were drawing simple line charts.